# Listbox in Wix chain bundle before installation. Is this possible?

Tags: listbox, wix, bundle

I have been searching for a way to place a listbox at the start of a Wix Chain Bundle in order to select the computer name to which the program should reference. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard bootstrapped, there is no simple way to modify the UI.

You can use a [custom managed bootstrapper](https://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/) in WPF or set [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/listbox.html) in the UI of the first Installer.